# Long URL as a command line doesn't work whereas a smaller URL works

Tags: opencv, command-line-arguments

I am trying to extract image frames from a video. I am passing the video URL as a command line argument. I am using a long URL as below.

> Extract.exe C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv

This doesn't work and it calls the help(), maybe because of argument count not being equal to 2. (The argument count shows 3).

When I put a short URL as below,

> Extract.exe F:\Wildlife.wmv

It works fine.

What could be the problem with the long URL command line ? How can I overcome this hurdle ?

You have some guidance for me ? Well, I am glad to have it with many thanks !!!

Comment: put it inside double quotes. like `Extract.exe "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have spaces in your path name

```
Extract.exe "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv"
```

should work.